# How to Sort a Table by Multiple Columns in SQL: Partitioning by ISIN and Sorting by Match_ID and Ref_Number

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a one table employee . need to sort the result .

---

```
match_id   isin   start_date    ref_number
1           A123   01-jan-2023    11
2           A123   02-jan-2023    11
3           A123   03-jan-2023    11
3           A123   03-jan-2023    12
2           A123   02-jan-2023    12
1           A123   01-jan-2023    22
1           A123   01-jan-2023    23
2           A123   02-jan-2023    22
3           A123   03-jan-2023    22
3           A123   03-jan-2023    23
1           A123   10-jan-2023    22
1           A123   01-jan-2023    12
2           A123   02-jan-2023    23
```

need output in below order ..
first partition by ISIN then sort based on group by match_id first
then order by start_date asc then ref_number wise sorting

---

```
match_id   isin   start_date    ref_number
1           A123   01-jan-2023    11
1           A123   01-jan-2023    12
2           A123   02-jan-2023    11
2           A123   02-jan-2023    12
3           A123   03-jan-2023    11
3           A123   03-jan-2023    12
1           A123   01-jan-2023    22
1           A123   01-jan-2023    23
2           A123   02-jan-2023    22
2           A123   02-jan-2023    23
3           A123   03-jan-2023    22
3           A123   03-jan-2023    23
1           A123   10-jan-2023    22
```

need to sort the output based on isin and then match_id and ref_number .

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag only the database you are using

Comment: MYSQL db i have used

Comment: Edit your question and remove unneeded tags please. Your question will get down-voted otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to partition by" vs. "to order by". It looks like you simply want your rows ordered first by isin, then by start_date, then by ref_number (`ORDER BY isin, start_date, ref_number`). I fthis isn't the case then please explain and amend your sample data to show such a case where "to partition by isin" is different from "to order by isin".

Comment: The updated question did not produce the expected results! Please provide specifics about what you require.

Comment: You have just updated your request and changed the sample data. Unfortunately, the task has not become any clearer to me. Quite the opposite. Now all your rows have the same isin, so we don't see any "partitioning". And moreover, the rows seem unordered. They are neither ordered by start_date nor by ref_number. Please explain by what rule you have created the order in your desired result.

Comment: i have just added one isin data  in the table . firstly group the match_id and then in that match_id suppose 2 rows are there then take the reference_number and sort with asc start_date then in that match_id group what is the reference_number there then next time go with that reference number and sort asc start_Date and so on @ThorstenKettner

Comment: "firstly group the match_id"? What does this mean? How would I "group" the match_id? Do you mean "sort"? "then take the reference_number and sort with asc start_date"? I don't understand how I would "take" the reference_number, but sort by start_date. I guess you want something like `ORDER BY isin, match_id, ref_number` or `ORDER BY isin, start_date, match_id, ref_number` or `ORDER BY isin, match_id, start_date, ref_number`. Just a normal sorting with a main column, a secondary column, and so on. There is nothing special about this, it seems, only that you make it sound complicated.

Comment: group matchid .. if first row of the match_id is 1 then that group of match_id contains 2 rows with the reference_number is 11,12 then next time take the row of reference number which contains 11,12 with asc start_date @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Sorry. Still no. I just don't understand what you are taking about. And it seems there is nobody else either trying to decipher this. Maybe you'll have to edit your request again and write next to each row why it is at this position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `row_number()` to give each order a unique id per partition:

```
select s.match_id, s.isin, start_date, s.ref_number
  from (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by isin order by match_id, ref_number) as rn
   from mytable
) as s
order by isin, rn
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mqGr0Wv3)

Comment: match_id is not mandatory to be start with 1 .. 2 .. and so on .. its just intergert number mainly sorting with start_date and ref_number but group with match_id

Comment: I have added a demo can you have a look

Comment: yes i had checked .. but match id can't be a numberic order .. it may be string but we have to gruop match id

Comment: The order will be correct whether it is numeric or alphanumeric.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details, I'm sure you will get an answer satisfy your requirements

Comment: yes sure i will edit my question

Comment: i have updated my question with one records also inserted plz check now